# what's the difference between spark-shell and submitted sbt programs

Tags: shell, apache-spark, sbt

Spark-shell can be used to interact with the distributed storage of data, then what is the essential difference between coding in spark-shell and uploading packaged sbt independent applications to the cluster operation?(I found a difference is sbt submit the job can be seen in the cluster management interface, and the shell can not) After all, sbt is very troublesome, and the shell is very convenient.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spark-shell gives you a bare console-like interface in which you can run your codes like individual commands. This can be very useful if you're still experimenting with the packages or debugging your code.

```
I found a difference is sbt submit the job can be seen in the cluster management interface, and the shell can not
```

Actually, spark shell also comes up in the job UI as "Spark-Shell" itself and you can monitor the jobs you are running through that.

Building spark applications using SBT gives you some organization in your development process, iterative compilation which is helpful in day-to-day development, and a lot of manual work can be avoided by this. If you have a constant set of things that you always run, you can simply run the same package again instead of going through the trouble of running the entire thing like commands. SBT does take some time getting used to if you are new to java style of development, but it can help maintain applications on the long run.

Comment: Thanks for you explanation. If i am to run a simple program on a large data set stored in HDFS, should i do it with spark-shell or should i submit it  using sbt? Are there differences in performance?

Comment: I would recommend running your program as a SBT application because of the above specified reasons. But if that is going to be only a one time thing and you are never going to do it again, I don't see anything wrong in doing it in shell.